# #define function with namespace in it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I'm working with some API which changes almost every year and i need to recompile some of my projects. To be capable working with one single file i want to redefine some of functions.
Here is the problem

```
#if API_VERSION < 12
#define somenamespace::someNEWfunction() someOLDfuncion()
#define somenamespace::someNEWnamespace                              //replace with nothing
#endif
```

So i have two situations. First one is when i have function that works exactly the same but was renamed and moved to it's own new namespace, so i need to just get rid of namespace part and replace it with old name.
And the second one is when function just moved to it's own new namespace but has same name.

Compiler wont let me compile it because of `::` sign.

Comment: You may be looking for a [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias). Macros are a wrong way to address this problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have a lot of function calls with this new namespace and i just need to get rid of it without changing the actual code.  Unfortunately, namespace aliases wont help me, and i don't see any other solution but just use macros :(

Comment: @Danchyg1337, how many are we talking about here? 100s? 1000s?

Comment: Well, as you've found, macros don't work either. You present an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Show an example of your current code, explain why it doesn't compile as-is and what you want to do to make it compile.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The actual code will not tell you more than example does. 
I cannot use typedef or namespace aliases because this `someNEWfunction` doesn't exist in api versions < 12. So that is the point, to replace not existing functions with existing.

Comment: @RSahu about 20-30. Not so much, but i don't want to have separate projects for each version of api.

Comment: You can provide your own implementation of `someNEWfunction` that would call `someOLDfuncion`. You can put it into `somenamespace` namespace.

Comment: `someNEWfunction = someOLDfunction` the difference is one of them was replaced to its own namespace. They are equal, i just need to call it without rewriting whole code. Is it possible to just replace one part or code with another?

Comment: And why can't you simply change the code? Why do you need a hack like this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Showing an example might clarify it. What does the code calling `someNEWfunction` look like? What does `someOLDfunction` declaration look like? Why again can't you simply write `someNEWfunction` that would turn around and call `someOLDfunction`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl i can. And i did it. I need it to make only one source file which can work with every api version, instead of having 2 source files for each api version in which only difference would be the name of functions.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't know how they look like. I'm calling the api functions. And before 12ver. it uses `someOLDfuncion()` and in 12+ versions it was replaced to `somenamespace`. So i have two different source files. One with using `somenamespace` and another without. I want to have only one source file but with #if at the start of file which will erase this `somenamespace` in code. Of course i can just rewrite it and keep two different source files, but i wanted to find a proper solution so i could have only one source file.

Comment: That one source file that you want to keep - what does **that** look like? Does it call `someOLDfuncion`, or `somenamespace::someNEWfunction`, or something else?

Comment: @Danchyg1337, I don't understand the breatdh and gravity of the problem from your post.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That one source file that i want to keep is the same file we are talking about all this time. 
I can either have 2 files or only one.
In case with one file i would have something like #define replace some function.
In case with 2 files i would have one file with using `somenamespace::someNEWfunction` and another file with using `someOLDfunction`.
I don't want to have 2 same source files with only one difference in it so i'm looking for a way to put it together. I should remind that that `somenamespace` is certain api namespace, not mine.

Comment: You can still write `namespace somenamespace { void someNEWfunction() { someOLDfunction(); } }`, even if `somenamespace` is also mentioned in some third-party header.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hm. Thank you. That was the solution. I tried it and it works. Type it in answers and i will set it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Macros replace *tokens*, not names.

You're attempting to replace three tokens at once (`somenamespace`, `::` and `someNEWfunction`).

You can't do that.

Instead, consider a [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias).